# How to create a transparent mask using shape

Tags: css, svg

Given I have a svg as follows:

```html
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#a)">
        <path d="M0 0h20v20H0V0z" fill="#0D4AF9" />
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
              d="M2 14.666a1.334 1.334 0 1 1 2.669.001A1.334 1.334 0 0 1 2 14.666zm4.667.667a.668.668 0 0 1 0-1.334h10.667a.667.667 0 1 1 0 1.334H6.667zM2 9.998a1.333 1.333 0 1 1 2.666 0 1.333 1.333 0 0 1-2.666 0zm4.667.667a.667.667 0 1 1 0-1.333h10.667a.666.666 0 1 1 0 1.333H6.667zM2 5.333a1.333 1.333 0 1 1 2.666.001A1.333 1.333 0 0 1 2 5.332v.001zm4.667.666a.667.667 0 1 1 0-1.333h10.667a.666.666 0 1 1 0 1.333H6.667z"
              fill="#fff"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
            <rect width="20" height="20" rx="2"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

which renders like:

[image]

How can one make those white lines and circles transparent? I tried creating masks but a total noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the `d` attributes of the 2 paths and use `fill-rule="evenodd"` so that the second part of the path became a hole.

```css
body{background:silver}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#a)">
        <path d="M0 0h20v20H0V0z 
        
        M2 14.666a1.334 1.334 0 1 1 2.669.001A1.334 1.334 0 0 1 2 14.666zm4.667.667a.668.668 0 0 1 0-1.334h10.667a.667.667 0 1 1 0 1.334H6.667zM2 9.998a1.333 1.333 0 1 1 2.666 0 1.333 1.333 0 0 1-2.666 0zm4.667.667a.667.667 0 1 1 0-1.333h10.667a.666.666 0 1 1 0 1.333H6.667zM2 5.333a1.333 1.333 0 1 1 2.666.001A1.333 1.333 0 0 1 2 5.332v.001zm4.667.666a.667.667 0 1 1 0-1.333h10.667a.666.666 0 1 1 0 1.333H6.667z" 
fill="#0D4AF9" fill-rule="evenodd" 
             />
    </g>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
            <rect width="20" height="20" rx="2"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

*Observation:* I've changed the size of the svg element. You can change it back to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Split out the element you want to another path, and then change the fill.